# Python - Error when trying to extract bytes from file

Tags: python, binary, byte

I am currently trying to extract the raw binary bytes from a file e.g. 000001001000

```
f = open(r"file.z", "rb")
try:
    byte = f.read();
    print int(byte)
finally:
    f.close()
```

The reason to why I used int(byte) was to have a peek at what the string looks like. (I couldn't print it because [Decode error - output not utf-8])

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\werdnakof\Downloads\test.py", line 9, in <module>
    print int(byte);
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '\x04\x80e\x06\xc0l\x06\xf0,\x02'
```

It returns \x04\x80e\x06\xc0l\x06\xf0,\x02

And I am not too sure where to go from here. I was told this is in 12 bit fixed with codes padded on the left.

Any advice or tips on how to solve this? All I want is the 12-bit number e.g.000001001000

Comment: try `int(byte.encode('utf-8'))`

Comment: Hi, it return:  UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0x80 in position 1: ordinal not in range(128)

Comment: can you provide `file.z` some lines here?

Comment: Sure, 
https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B84_Z1V4nj9SS0x4MlR0a2poMkE/view?usp=sharing

Comment: please copy paste some line here. cannot extract your file in drive

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use encode and bin:

```
 bin(int(b.encode("hex"),16))

In [27]: b='\x04\x80e\x06\xc0l\x06\xf0,\x02'
In [28]: int(b.encode("hex"),16)
Out[28]: 21257928890331299851266L
In [29]: bin(int(b.encode("hex"),16))
Out[29]: '0b10010000000011001010000011011000000011011000000011011110000001011000000001



with open("file.z","rb") as f:
    for line in f:
        print(int(line.encode("hex"), 16))
```

Comment: Hi, I am a bit confused with the base 16 inside int() after you have encoded it with hex...can you describing what you are doing?

Comment: you encode the string to hex, then convert to `int` using base `16` for hex. If it were binary you would use base `2` for octal base `8` etc..

Comment: I have a follow up question, how can you tell this is base 16 just from looking at b?

Comment: But why encode string to hex? (sorry if I am sounding stupid but I am quite new to this...)

Comment: so we can cast to int, if you tried using `struct.unpack` with `L` you would have to read 8 bytes or `i` you would have to read 4 bytes. Encoding as hex and casting using base 16 allows you to read any length of bytes

Answer (score 0):

To print the contents of a binary string, you can convert it to hex-representation:

```
print byte.encode('hex')
```

For reading binary structures, you can use the struct-module.

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this

```
f = open("file.z", "rb")
try:
    byte = f.read();
    print(bin(int(str(byte).encode("hex"),16)))
finally:
    f.close()
```

From Padraic Cunningham's answer